# MongoDB "unable to find index for $geoNear query"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, geojson

I've searched these boards and have found similar problems but nothing that seems to resolve the same error I'm having with a query.

Sample GeoJSON data in my mongoDB:

```
{
    "type" : "SOMEPOLYGON",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [
                            -83.606133,
                            36.606195
                        ],
                        [
                            -77.802765,
                            39.126537
                        ],
                        [
                            -75.889428,
                            36.555319
                        ],
                        [
                            -83.606133,
                            36.606195
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "an_id" : "22D49CAA-24B8-420E-A47B-10882578A6DC",
                "time" : "2019-02-0419:58:22"
            }
        }
    ]
}


{
    "type" : "SET OF POINTS",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                    -102.990147,
                    36.983626
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "advertiser_id" : "22D49CAA-24B8-420D-A47B-10882578A6DC",
                "time" : "2021-02-04 19:58:22"
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                    -94.629912,
                    36.983626
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "advertiser_id" : "22D49CAA-24B8-420D-A47B-10882578A6DC",
                "time" : "2021-02-05 08:08:04"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am having issues trying to perform the following query:

```
db.events.find({
    geometry: {
        $near: {
            $geometry: { 
                type:"Point", 
                coordinates:[<long>,<lat>]},
                $minDistance: 0,
                $maxDistance:500000
            }
        }
})
```

When I do, I get the following error:

Error: error: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : **"error processing query: ns=local.eventsTree: GEONEAR  field=geometry maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query"**,
"code" : 291,
"codeName" : "NoQueryExecutionPlans"
}

I have created a 2Dsphere index with the following:

"MongoDB Enterprise > db.events.createIndex({geometry:"2d"})
{
"numIndexesBefore" : 1,
"numIndexesAfter" : 2,
"createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
"ok" : 1
}
"

I've confirmed that my index has been created:

MongoDB Enterprise > db.events.getIndexes()

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "geometry" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "geometry_2dsphere",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

I seem to have no problem doing the following geospatial query:

```
db.events.find({geometry:{$geoWithin:{$centerSphere:[[<long>,<lat>],7]}}})
```

One query works but the other does not. I've tried changing the index by specifying a nested key for the location (e.g. "features.geometry", etc). I've also tried changing the index to 2D. Nothing seems to resolve this error. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: The index in on a top-level field named 'geometry', but I don't see that field in the sample data.

Comment: "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Polygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [
                            -83.606133,
                            36.606195
                        ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referring to fields that are not at the top-level of the document, you must use dot notation.

As written, that query and index both refer to a `geometry` field that is a sibling of the `type` and `features` field.  Since those fields don't exist, the index has no entries and the find query is attempting to match against undefined.

For a collection containing those sample documents, the index would need to be:

```
  {"features.geometry":"2dsphere"}
```

or

```
  {"features.geometry":"2d"}
```

And the query would need to be

```
db.events.find({
    "features.geometry": {
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks Joe!! Simple yet stupid mistake on my part. This did the trick!